# Which factory reset should I use?

Tags: factory-reset, motorola-droid-3

I have the motorola droid 3 and it can be factory reset from either the settings menu or the recovery menu. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Results should be the same, so you can use either.

The item in the recovery menu you could count as a "backup switch": How else could you reset a device which refuses to completely boot up? That would otherwise be a "vicious circle": In order to boot up you'd neet to factory-reset – but in order to factory-reset, you'd need to boot up. So with the recovery menu, you've got a "reserve switch" for cases like that.

The switch in settings, on the other hand, is easier to find for "novice users" not aware of those "Vulcan nerve pinches" (or "three finger salutes", whatever you prefer) to boot the device into "special modes".

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a complete out-of-the-box experience, i would suggest using the factory reset option in the boot menu. This can be accessed like so; With the device powered off, press volume up and down and the power button all at the same time. Then using the volume down key to scroll down to the factory reset option and select using the volume up button. ***BE AWARE: This method will erase all personal storage and the sd card, back up data and remove the sd card before starting this process***

Comment: There is no boot menu in Android. Are you referring to recovery options? Second, ever since Android 5 this out-of-the-box experience cannot be replicated because of factory reset protection. On first screen the system would demand last Google account to setup the device. That breaks out of the box experience. Besides, factory reset, when it comes to deleting user data, works the same way, whether done using Settings app or recovery.